# Extract values from JSON with nesting

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with taking all values under the "id_ref_directory" keys.

I have a temp table:

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMP TABLE parsed_json(
    var_key text, 
    var_value text NOT NULL)
ON COMMIT DROP;
```

I have a JSON, in temp table:

```
INSERT INTO parsed_json(var_key, var_value)
SELECT * 
FROM json_each_text(var_in_json::json)
WHERE value IS NOT NULL and LENGTH(value) != 0;
```

I have var int[]:

```
var_territory_list := (SELECT var_value FROM parsed_json WHERE var_key = 'territory_custom');
```

And I have JSON like this in "value" field:

```
[{"name_directory": "ЯПОНИЯ", "id_ref_directory": 38},
{"name_directory": "ЯПОН", "id_ref_directory": 39}, 
{"name_directory": "ЯП", "id_ref_directory": 40}]}
```

I need to write into `var_territory_list`this from JSON abowe (values of keys "id_ref_directory"):

```
[38, 39, 40]
```

I thought that I could solve everything with simple operators like `#>` but I failed. Maybe it is necessary to do it through a cycle? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want an int array as the result (`integer[]`)  or a JSON value that contains an array? Because `[38, 39, 40]` is the standard display format for JSON arrays, not for `integer[]`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I rewrite my question. Sorry

Comment: @S-Man I rewrite my question. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Click: step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=220a19f9eadcbc023b034a637143344f)

```
SELECT
    jsonb_agg(elems -> 'id_ref_directory')
FROM mytable,
    jsonb_array_elements(mydata -> 'territory_custom') AS elems
```

1. `jsonb_array_elements()` gives you one row per array element
2. `elems -> 'id_ref_directory'` gives you the expected values of these elements
3. `jsonb_agg()` aggregates them into a JSON array

If you want an `int` array:

```
SELECT
    array_agg((elems ->> 'id_ref_directory')::int)
FROM mytable,
    jsonb_array_elements(mydata -> 'territory_custom') AS elems
```

1. Instead of `jsonb_agg()` use `array_agg()` after casting the elements into `int` values

---

**Postgres 12** allows to use JSONpath:

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7b285152ebd8661618b0eb574c96da83)

```
SELECT
    jsonb_path_query_array(mydata, '$.territory_custom.id_ref_directory') elems
FROM mytable
```

1. `'$.territory_custom.id_ref_directory'` gives you all expected elements
2. The function aggregates the result into an array

If you want an `int` array:

```
SELECT
    array_agg(elems::int)
FROM mytable,
    jsonb_path_query(mydata, '$.territory_custom.id_ref_directory') elems
```

1. Calculate all elements into one row per element
2. Aggregate these elements with `array_agg()` after casting them into `int` values